# Swift - is there a way to match an error without throwing?

Tags: swift

In some cases, an error is provided as an argument rather than being thrown. One example could be completion handlers where `Result<T, Error>` is provided. I would like to match the error without throwing it.

**Example of error matching by throwing it:**

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case error
}

func process(error: Error) {
    do {
        throw error
    } catch MyError.error {
        print("this is it")
    } catch {
        print("unknown error")
    }
}

process(error: MyError.error)
```

**UPDATE:**

The matching should work even for the system provided errors, like `URLError` which are not `enum` types.

```
func process(error: Error) {
    do {
        throw error
    } catch URLError.timedOut {
        print("this is not it")
    } catch URLError.cancelled {
        print("this is it")
    } catch {
        print("unknown error")
    }
}

process(error: URLError(.cancelled))
```

Comment: Note that you cannot `throw` a `URLError.Code`, since it doesn't conform to the `Error` type, and that the code you have now posted above doesn't compile, because you attempt to give the `process` function an argument of type `URLError` when it expects `Error`.

Comment: Yes, you can. These errors are bridged from objc and are indeed throwable. If it didn't conform to the Error type, you wouldn't be able to get it in a parameter of the Error type.

Comment: Sorry. I mixed `URLError` with `URLError.Code`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use the `if case` syntax.**

In your example,

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case error
}

func process(error: Error) {
    if case MyError.error = error {
        print("this is it")
    } else {
        print("unknown error")
    }
}

process(error: MyError.error)
```

Comment: Nice. This works even for system provided errors, like URLError which are not enum types.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to match errors that are not thrown. A way that keeps the code simple with many errors to check for, is the use of a `switch` statement:

#### Update:

I have now updated the code to include the `URLError` that you have requested.

```
enum CommonError: Error {
    case input
    case output
}

enum RareError: Error {
    case language
    case mathematics
}

let error: Error = RareError.language
// or
let error: Error = URLError(.cancelled)

switch error {
case CommonError.input:     print("Common input error")
case CommonError.output:    print("Common output error")
case RareError.language:    print("Rare language error") // This is executed
case RareError.mathematics: print("Rare mathematics error")

case URLError.cancelled: print("URLError -> cancelled") // - or this
case URLError.timedOut:  print("URLError -> timed out")

default: print("The error is unknown; maybe you should consider throwing it now?")
}
```